# Retrofit URI with comma separated params

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using `retrofit:2.1.0` and I am trying to construct a GET (never seen before) URI like so:

`https://api.endpoint.net/v1/getValues?userID=456&imgID=37&infoToken=values:imgSize=200,imgTypeDefault=true&cropped=false`

In the above URI, I have comma separated query parameters in `infoToken=values:imgSize=200,imgTypeDefault=true` and while `imgSize` is dynamically populated, `imgTypeDefault` is static, and :
`userID`, `imgID` are also dynamically populated.

`@GET("/v1/getValues?infoToken=values:imgSize=,imgTypeDefault=true&cropped=false
Call<Images> getImageListWithSize(@Query("userID") String userID,
                            @Query("imgID") int imgID,
                            @Query(value = "imgSize", encoded = true) int size);`

Note: since I wasn't sure how the value will be passed to comma separated parameter in the URI, I set `infoToken=values:imgSize=` which appears incorrect

and I submit the request:

`Call<Images> call = apiEndpointI.getImageListWithSize(currUser.getUserID,
                                currUser.getImgID(), currUser.getImgSize());`

Here is the request URI being fired from logs:

`https://api.endpoint.net/v1/getValues?userID=XXX&imgID=37&infoToken=values:imgSize=,imgTypeDefault=true&cropped=false&imgSize=200`

as you can see from the above request, when `@Query` is used it will prefix w/ `&` even though I set `encoded = true`. Instead, I want `infoToken=values:imgSize=` to be assigned with value of `imgSize` I am passing in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. So, now my `GET` looks like this:

`@GET("/v1/getValues?cropped=false
Call<Images> getImageListWithSize(@Query("userID") String userID,
                            @Query("imgID") int imgID,
                            @Query("infoToken") String infoToken);`

and I declare the infoToken as:

`int size = getSize(); //200 for example
String infoToken = "values:imgSize=" + size + ",imgTypeDefault=true";`

and with all of that I submit the request:

`Call<Images> call = apiEndpointI.getImageListWithSize(currUser.getUserID,
                                currUser.getImgID(), infoToken);`